# Adding async keyword to script tag using HtmlTextWriter

Tags: htmltextwriter

We are dynamically adding script tags to a page using HtmlTextWriter, which works great.  We have a few that need to have async keyword added and I'm not sure how to do it.

I want the tag to look like this.

```
<script id="my_script"  async   type="text/javascript"  src="myscript.js"></script>
```

My method that builds the tags look like this.

```
    internal static void RenderJavaScriptInclude(HtmlTextWriter writer, string      filePath, string Id)
{
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, Id);
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/javascript");
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, filePath);
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Script);
    writer.RenderEndTag();
}
```

How can I modify to add "async"?

Much thanks as always,

Rhonda

Comment: What do you need to make async?  You can add the `async` decorator to `RenderJavaScriptInclude` but I don't see where you require it.

Comment: I'm integrating a third party application and they require it to be in the tag exactly like this.  This is from the integration document.

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC …EN" 
<html> 
<head>  <title>  YourWebsite.com </title>  
</head> 
<body> 
<script id="bevyup_partner_script" async type="text/javascript" 
src="//b.bevyup.com/GetTemplateScript/bevyup_partner_id"></script> 
 
...the standard document body of your site… 
</body> 
</html>

Comment: Ahh, right in the output.  As far as I know the format should be `async="async"` Which is basically writer.AddAttribute("async", "async").  as far as I can tell this will do what you want (i.e. output the attribute without the value.  Otherwise, have you tried `writer.AddAttribute("async", string.Empty)` or `writer.AddAttribute("async", null)`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of the [RenderBeginTag](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Web/UI/HTMLTextWriter.cs.html#588692749ea23127) method, any attribute with value equals to `null` (but not `String.Empty`) will be rendered without quoted value. So, just call `writer.AddAttribute("async", null);` before calling of `RenderBeginTag`.